# How do I get my other computer to connect to the internet?

Tags: router, vpn, routing, dir-300

I have a WAN VPN with dynamic IP. I have configured my **D-Link DIR-300** router so my computer is now connected to the internet.

I want internet also on another computer in the room. Although I've plugged in the cable on the other computer, it doesn't connect to internet. I think it is because I can't configure routing in the router panel.

My problem is that I don't know which IP, Subnet Mask and Gateway to assign to get my second computer to connect to internet because I have **dynamic IP**.

Which values should I enter? Do I need to configure some internet configuration on the second computer which I want to connect to the internet?

Comment: Why not let the other computer obtain IP address automatically?